# In Goldberg-Tarjan's algorithm for finding the max flow, why is $d(v)$ a lower bound for the shortest path?

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, network-flow

I hope my question is precise enough. In Goldberg-Tarjan's algorithm (also push-relabel algorithm, and other names) a distance (or label- as it's called in my lecture) function $d(v)$ is needed. This function is defined as

$d: V \to \mathbb{N}_0:$
$\forall (v,w) \in E: d(v) \le d(w) + 1$
For the start of the flow $s: d(s) = n = |V|$
For the end of the flow $t: d(t) = 0$

Now for the proof of the correctness of this algorithm the next step (in our lecture) is to show that

$d_x(v,t) \ge d(v)$

with $d_x(v,t)$ being the length of a shortest (number of edges) v-w-path in $G$. This means, that $d(v)$ is a lower bound for the amount of edges in a shortes path from $v$ to $t$.

Now comes the question: Why is it a *lower* bound? If $n$ is the amount of edges in the graph, and $d(s)=n$, isn't the shortest path from $s$ to $t$ bound to have *less than* or equal to $n$ edges?

I'm sorry for not providing any sources to this, but none of my sources are in English, and you can easily look up ones of your own on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E2%80%93relabel_maximum_flow_algorithm) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion comes from your condition $\forall (v,w)\in E$. The labels must be respected in the **residual graph** $G_f$, hence the correct condition is $\forall (v,w)\in E_f: d(v)\leq d(w)+1$.

In particular, the algorithm starts with a flow that removes all outgoing edges from $s$, so actually $t$ is not reachable from $t$ (again, in $G_f$).

For a clear exposition, I would recommend the book Algorithm Design (Kleinberg-Tardos), they go in detail in chapter 7.4.

Cheers